# SDL_Image return NULL when trying to load texture

Tags: c++, texture-mapping, opengl-3, sdl-2, sdl-image

I have model loaded to my screen, but having trouble getting it's texture read. Whenever I try to load the model's texture, it returns NULL. The model and texture resides within the same directory, I can't figure out why the program is having problems. While the program runs, the error I receive from `IMG_GetError()` is:

> Couldn't open (location)/image.jpg

Here is how it is loading:

```
bool CTexture::load()
{
    surface = IMG_Load(_fileName.c_str());

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &_textureObj);

    if (surface == NULL)
    {
        std::cout 
        << "---------------\n" 
        << IMG_GetError() 
        << "\n---------------\n" 
        << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }

    _width = surface->w;
    _height = surface->h;
    _bpp = surface->pitch;

    if (surface->format->BytesPerPixel == 3)
        _mode = GL_RGB;

    else if (surface->format->BitsPerPixel == 4)
        _mode = GL_RGBA;

    else
    {
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        return false;
    }

    glBindTexture(_textureTarget, _textureObj);
    glTexImage2D(_textureTarget, 0, _mode, surface->w, surface->h, 0, _mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
    setFiltering(GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR);

    _isLoaded = true;

    if (surface)
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    std::cout << _fileName << std::endl;

    return _isLoaded;
```

}

My DLLs are **libjpeg-9, libpng16-16, libtiff and libwebp-4.**

Comment: Which IDE are you using ? And what is the working directory specified in your IDE ?

Comment: Also what platform are you working on? Have you tried loading the image using absolute path rather than relative? Have you tried a different image/image format?